# Как оформляют подалгоритмы?

Tags: алгоритм, блок-схема, гост, документация

Добрый день!

Пишу диплом, оформляю алгоритмы работы программы(ГОСТ 19.401-78)...

Появилось два вопроса:

1. При переносе связи(между прерванными линиями) в области одной страницы использую "кружек". В кружке стоит номер связи. Есть аналогичные переносы и на других страницах. Вопрос в том, нужно ли учитывать нумерацию предыдущих кружков или можно заново начинать нумерацию с "1"?
2. Есть блоки типа"Прочитать данные из файла". Этот блок я более детально расписываю на другом листе... А вопрос в том, можно ли так делать и если да, то как оформляют такой "подблок-подмодуль"? Оформляют как обычно(начало подмодуля->что-то...->конец подмодуля)?

Comment: А не сделать ли глобальную схему архитектуры, а затем отдельно нарисовать интересующие модули? Как бы, с разным масштабом абстракции.

Comment: Я так и делаю. Но глобальная схема получилась сама по себе очень большой, даже с упрощениями. Отсюда и нужны переносы на одной и разных страницах. А вот насчет масштаба абстракций, как показать что это как бы часть большого алгоритма? Подписать - это само собой, а оформить на схеме как? Как обычный алгоритм?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** ГОСТ 19.701-90 не содержит отдельных символов для переноса между страницами, как это было в более старых ГОСТах - а потому номер переноса должен быть полностью уникальным в пределах алгоритма.

**2.** Вызов "подалгоритма" обычно оформляется блоком "3.2.2.1. Предопределенный процесс" или "3.3.2.1. Передача управления" (второй символ может использоваться только в схемах взаимодействия разных программ).

Сам подалгоритм оформляется как обычный алгоритм. В терминальных символах можно написать "Начало подпрограммы" и "Конец подпрограммы" вместо обычных "Начало" и "Конец". Если подразумевается использование структурных исключений - в подпрограмме может появиться второй выход, "Ошибка".

Передача параметров в подалгоритм внутри подалгоритма выглядит как обычный символ "3.1.1.1. Данные", точно так же обозначается и возвращаемое значение. То, что это именно параметры и возвращаемое значение, требуется указывать уже внутри символа.

Еще один вариант оформления подалгоритмов - подробное представление, пункт 4.1.8. Внутри-сверху любого символа может быть нарисована горизонтальная полоса, означающая, что данный символ подробнее раскрыт в другом месте. Подробное представление оформляется так же, как и подпрограмма, за тем исключением что никакие параметры не вводятся явно символом "3.1.1.1. Данные", вместо этого внутри символа "доступны" все те переменные что есть снаружи.

Ваш блок "прочитать данные из файла" я бы оформил как символ "3.1.1.1. Данные" с полосой.